# $\ell^p$ norm induces a metric

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I'am having troubles proving that $\ell^p$ metric is real-valued (finite). Written out, Let p $\geq 1$ be a real number, and $x=(\epsilon_j)$, $y = (\eta_j)$ sequences (bounded or unbounded) of numbers such that
$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\epsilon_j|^p, \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\eta_j|^p < \infty$$.

How it follows $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\epsilon_{j} - \eta_{j}|^p < \infty$?

Comment: You can try applying Minkowski's inequality

Comment: In particular, if you happen to from Minkowski that $\|\cdot\|_{p}$ defines a norm, then what you are asking is a special case of the fact that every norm induces metric by defining $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$.